# overwrite app-convert.properties file in highchart-export-web war

Tags: highcharts

I have used highchart-export-web war in my project. I want to change app-convert.properties file of the war on runtime. (while extracting war to deploy folder. )

Comment: What exactly is the question? You want to edit app-convert.properties file? Then you should rebuild a .war file as instructed in [Highcharts Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server).

Comment: @kacper Thanks Yes i rebuild a war and it worked for me